# Re-encode and clean text files in Terminal

Tags: macos

I have a batch of text files of indeterminate encoding that I need to clean of unusual characters.  I've used python's [chadet library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323770/character-detection-in-a-text-file-in-python-using-the-universal-encoding-detect) to establish that they 87% conform to ISO-8859-2, but they still contain non-conforming characters which prevent them reading into R - [described in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19301265/reading-in-data-with-unusual-characters/19323168?noredirect=1#comment28640591_19323168).  I wonder if there is a way - preferably a command line method - to batch clean these and convert to say UTF-8, with any non-confirming characters being changed to something like '~'.  Very grateful for assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried with `iconv`? I don't know if OSX contains this command but here's an example:

```
iconv -t UTF-8 myfile.txt
```

If that fails, try to transliterate it:

```
iconv -t UTF-8//TRANSLIT myfile.txt
```

Update (from the comments):

> After a bit of experimentation `iconv -t UTF-8//TRANSLIT -c infile > outfile.txt` did the job. Thanks guys.

Comment: Alas I get `iconv: SMKA121212 copy:13:121: cannot convert`

Comment: Edited my answer, try with //TRANSLIT as shown above

Comment: OS X iconv does not seem to support transliteration.

Comment: try putting it in quotes `"UTF-8//TRANSLIT"` or try using `-sc` options -- it will discard the erroneous characters

Comment: After a bit of experimentation `iconv -t UTF-8//TRANSLIT -c infile > outfile.txt` did the job. Thanks guys.

Comment: The libiconv implementation of `iconv` that comes with OS X does support `//TRANSLIT` and `//IGNORE`. See `man iconv_open`.